# libtorrent cannot build with VS2005

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2005, libtorrent

I try to build libtorrent(rasterbar- libtorrent). It cannot be build. the build log is over there http://dl.dropbox.com/u/359998/build.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libtorrent(rasterbar- libtorrent) cannot be built with Visual Studio 2005.